# database design with event start and end time

Tags: database-design, triggers

I have a mysql db with a table called `event_table` that looks like this

```
var Schema = {
    event_start: DataTypes.DATE,
    event_end: DataTypes.DATE
}
```

Right now when I want to query existing events I can do

```
SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE event_end >= curdate() and event_start <= curdate()
```

I am thinking to add a field called `if_existing_event` and write a small program that runs every once in a while and assign true or false to this field.  So in the future I can simplify the query to become

```
SELECT * FROM event_table WHERE if_existing_event = true;
```

Is there's a way that I can setup a trigger or do something with the db to achieve this?  And is it a recommended way to simplify the query?

Comment: You wrote mysql but added a tag for sql-server-triggers. sql server supports computed columns that you can use for this purpose, I don't know about mysql.

Comment: I realized I can use ORM such as sequelize to generate a virtual field getter and setter to achieve this instead of a real field.  Maybe I don't need a trigger or program update at all?

Answer (score 1):

Whether an event is existing or not is a 'derived value' which is derived from event_start date and event_end date. As per normalization rules and specifically 3rd Normal Form, derived values should be removed from the table.

However, de-normalization can be done if it yields substantial performance benefits. However, in your case since its just a comparison less and that too only if the first clause 'event_end >= curdate()' is true is not so much of a  gain to lose the benefits of normalization for.

Comment: ya. just thinking it might be easier to query the right stuff without missing something in the future or when other people are working on it..

Answer (score 1):

How often is "every once in a while"? Suppose you query *current events* and a lot of events end five minutes from now. Then there's a good chance they will still show up if you requery ten minutes from now. The best design would have the events removed from the result set at the very instant they become no longer current.

You supplied the solution in your first query. Make that definition of a view called, oh, something like *Current_Events*. Then the query

```
select * from current_events;
```

will return only current events. Events that ceased being current mere milliseconds before the query is executed will not appear.

I am a great user of views. I would think nothing of having a couple of dozen views for most major tables. This greatly simplifies application queries.

```
select  *
from    ViewThatPresentsDataJustTheRightWay;
```

Comment: true just that there are multiple query conditions like date, used, used_by... etc so if I don't come up with those virtual field chances are I might miss something that I don't know..

Comment: but anyway I think I can use ORMs the come up with virtual field getter and setters and it's much easier to manage than creating a new field I guess..